# build native code for android 64-bit arm architecture

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arm, x86-64

We have a native .so file for 32-bit Android. We need to port it to 64-bit Android code (for Android L). We are not using NDK to build. We use make files and arm-linux-androideabi-g++ with command line options to build our source.

Can someone please let me know how to port our code to 64-bit Android platform?

Comment: The first step would be to get a version of GCC targeting AArch64 (and x86-64 and MIPS64 if you care about those).

Comment: You are not using NDK's build. You are probably still using NDK's parts to build. Newer NDK has GCC AARCH64 toolchain, and NDK has instructions to setup "standalone" toolchains.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new standalone toolchain (same process you used to generate `arm-linux-androideabi-g++`) for arm64 (requires NDK r10).

http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html